# how to bring a particular section up in webpage to mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for create a website. I need a single section to use in another place in mobile view, but i don't want duplicate code.

Comment: if you don't want to duplicate code, then you definitely can achieve that using jQuery. You can share your link where you are facing this problem.

Comment: @Shilpa Gupta Can you put your code here else create plunker for this?

Comment: ok dhruv i  ll thank you..

Answer (score 0):

you can set display of page in another plase with diferente width using css style.like below code:

@media only screen and (max-width : 1100px) {your styles ...}

@media only screen and (max-width : 843px) {your styles ...}

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $html = $('html');

    $window.resize(function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 514) {
            return $html.addClass('mobile');
        }

        $html.removeClass('mobile');
    }).trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

```css
html {
    background: white;
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
html.mobile {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
}

Like that you can add section according to screen size.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I am text.</>
```